# a game where you guess the safe code

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a game I'm programming where you need to guess the secret safe code.
I'm new to this so sorry for the poor code.
I can't figure how to manage all the instances that could appear.

```
import random
import time
from colored import fg
    
pattern = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
greenText = fg('green')
redText = fg('red')
white = fg('white')


def checkScore(user_guess, user_guess_fixed):
    print("in checkScore")
    secretStop = 1
    while secretStop != 'q':
        print("in loop")
        try:
            print("in try")

            # convert input to list
            num = list(map(int, user_guess_fixed))
            secretStop = 'q'
            # # check if number is in the right range
            # if 0 < int(user_guess_fixed[0]) < 20 and 0 < int(user_guess_fixed[1]) < 20 and 0 < int(user_guess_fixed[2]) < 20 and 0 < int(user_guess_fixed[3]) < 20:
            #     # num = int(user_guess_fixed)
            #     print(num)
            #     secretStop = 'q'

        # catching error if we couldnt make it a list
        except ValueError or TypeError:
            print("in execpt")
            time.sleep(2)
            # try again
            user_guess_fixed = input("Invalid Entry. Guess the code again! \n(remember, 4 blocks, each one is a number between 1-20, e.g '1 2 3 4')\n").split()
            try:
                # try to make the new input a list
                num = list(map(int, user_guess_fixed))
                secretStop = 'q'
            # catching errors
            except:
                print("bad")
        MainCheck(user_guess, user_guess_fixed)

    # checking if its a win or a lose
def MainCheck(user_guess, user_guess_fixed):
    print("strating maincheck")
    if 0 < int(user_guess_fixed[0]) < 20 and 0 < int(user_guess_fixed[1]) < 20 and 0 < int(user_guess_fixed[2]) < 20 and 0 < int(user_guess_fixed[3]) < 20:
        if user_guess_fixed[0] == pattern[0] and user_guess_fixed[1] == pattern[1] and user_guess_fixed[2] == pattern[2] and user_guess_fixed[3] == pattern[3]:
            WinningMessage()
        else:
            LosingMessage(user_guess_fixed)
    else:
        checkScore(user_guess, user_guess_fixed)

def WinningMessage():
    print("in WinningMessage")
    print("YOU JUST WON! INCREDIBLE!")


def LosingMessage(user_guess_fixed):

    print("in LosingMessage")
    if user_guess_fixed[0] == pattern[0]:
        colored0 = (greenText + user_guess_fixed[0])
    else:
        colored0 = (redText + user_guess_fixed[0])

    if user_guess_fixed[1] == pattern[1]:
        colored1 = (greenText + user_guess_fixed[1])
    else:
        colored1 = (redText + user_guess_fixed[1])

    if user_guess_fixed[2] == pattern[2]:
        colored2 = (greenText + user_guess_fixed[2])
    else:
        colored2 = (redText + user_guess_fixed[2])

    if user_guess_fixed[3] == pattern[3]:
        colored3 = (greenText + user_guess_fixed[3])
    else:
        colored3 = (redText + user_guess_fixed[3])
    colorsMerged = colored0 + " " + colored1 + " " + colored2 + " " + colored3
    print(colorsMerged)
    print("You Lost. but, you can buy another round just for 5$")
    user_decision = (
        "To buy another round send *play*, to to exit send *exit*")


def Run():
    print("in run")
    user = input("Enter your name: ")
    bet_coins = 7000

    # ******************
    secret_code = ['12', '1', '7', '4']
    # ******************

    print("Welcome to the safe game, " +
          user[0].upper() + user[1::].lower() + ".")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Your goal here is to guess the safe key.")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Here's how you start:")
    time.sleep(3)
    user_decision = input(
        "To start send *play*, for rules send *rules*\n").lower()
    time.sleep(2)
    while user_decision != 'play' and user_decision != 'rules':
        time.sleep(3)
        user_decision = input(
            "Oops, invalid entry. To play send *play*, for rules send *rules*\n").lower()
    time.sleep(2)
    StartGame(user_decision)


def StartGame(user_decision):
    print("in startgame")
    if user_decision == 'play':
        user_guess = input("HERE WE GO! guess the code! \n(remember, 4 blocks, each one is a number between 1-20, e.g '1 2 3 4'):\n")
        user_guess_fixed = user_guess.split()
        checkScore(user_guess, user_guess_fixed)

    elif user_decision == 'rules':
        print("Playing this game is not that diffuclt. your goal here is the guess the code to the secret safe.")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("The safe contains 4 blocks. each one is a number between 1-20.")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("When you guess make sure to type at this format (e.g '1 2 3 4'). Starting game:")
        time.sleep(5)
        user_guess = input(
            "HERE WE GO! guess the code! \n(remember, 4 blocks, each one is a number between 1-20, e.g '1 2 3 4')\n")
        user_guess_fixed = user_guess.split()
        checkScore(user_guess, user_guess_fixed)


Run()
print(white)
```

Comment: Does your program work? If not this is off topic.

Comment: “sorry for the poor code” You can get advice on improving your code here. Instead of apologizing, ask about ways to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by instances, but this code needs a lot of work.

`pattern` is constant - fine; but then its variable name should be capitalised. It should also be a list of ints and not strings.

`checkScore` (which should be `check_score` by PEP8) has confused responsibilities. It should only check the answer, and not also do input parsing.

Based on `print("in WinningMessage")` etc., this is evidence that you're not properly using an interactive debugger. This is crucial; get and learn a good IDE like PyCharm, add breakpoints and step through. Delete your debugging `print`s.

You say that the user can buy another round, but this seems like a lie because the cost is never deducted from their coin balance.

`secret_code` is ignored and `pattern` used instead, so delete the former.

Delete all of your `sleep()`s. This is not a useful UI feature.

### Suggested

```
PATTERN = [1, 2, 3, 4]
COST = 5


def run() -> None:
    user = input("Enter your name: ")
    print(
        f"Welcome to the safe game, {user.title()}"
        "\nYour goal here is to guess the safe key."
        "\nHere's how you start:"
    )

    while True:
        user_decision = input("To start type *play*, for rules type *rules*: ").lower()
        if user_decision == 'play':
            break
        if user_decision == 'rules':
            show_rules()
            break
        print('Oops, invalid entry.')

    play()


def play() -> None:
    for bet_coins in range(7_000, 0, -COST):
        answer = get_guess()
        if answer == PATTERN:
            print("YOU JUST WON! INCREDIBLE!")
            break

        if bet_coins < COST:
            break

        print(f"You lost, but you can buy another round for just ${COST}")
        user_decision = input("To buy another round type *play*, to exit type *exit*: ").strip().lower()
        if user_decision != 'play':
            break


def get_guess() -> list[int]:
    while True:
        print()
        user_guess = input(
            "HERE WE GO! Guess the code!"
            "\n(Remember, 4 blocks, each one is a number between 1-20, e.g '1 2 3 4'): ")

        try:
            answer = [int(g) for g in user_guess.split()]
            if all(1 <= a <= 20 for a in answer):
                return answer
        except ValueError:
            pass

        print('Invalid entry.')


def show_rules() -> None:
    print(
        "Playing this game is not that difficult. Your goal here is the guess the code to the secret safe."
        "\nThe safe contains 4 blocks. each one is a number between 1-20."
        "\nWhen you guess make sure to type at this format (e.g '1 2 3 4')."
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```